# different format / efficiency for MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery

This is a question of different way to run this statement or a way to make it more efficient really.

This statement is meant to name all the staff who will leave the site the soonest, but they staff also have to be on site today.

```
SELECT 
    e.EmpName,
    cs.SiteName
FROM
    Employee e
INNER JOIN
    EmployeeAssignment ea
ON
    e.EmpId = ea.EmpId
INNER JOIN
    CustomerSite cs
ON
    ea.CustId = cs.CustId
WHERE 
    e.EmpId IN
    (
    SELECT
        ea.EmpId
    FROM
        EmployeeAssignment ea
    WHERE
         ea.EndDate IN
            (
            SELECT 
                MIN(ea.EndDate)
            FROM 
                 EmployeeAssignment ea
             WHERE
                GETDATE() BETWEEN ea.StartDate AND ea.EndDate
             GROUP BY 
                CustId
             ));
```

if anyone cna think of a better way to write this please reply thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  
    e.EmpName, 
    cs.SiteName 
FROM 
    Employee e 
INNER JOIN 

(
 SELECT  custid,empid from EmployeeAssignment ea1 where Enddate=( 
             select MIN(ea.EndDate) 
            FROM  
                 EmployeeAssignment ea 
             WHERE 
                GETDATE() BETWEEN ea.StartDate AND ea.EndDate 
                and ea.custid=ea1.custid
             )
) as ea
ON 
    e.EmpId = ea.EmpId 
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerSite cs 
ON 
    ea.CustId = cs.CustId
```

Comment: says that the last ea.CustId is a invalid column name??

Answer (score 0):

This may, or may not work:

```
SELECT 
    e.EmpName,
    cs.SiteName
FROM
    Employee e
INNER JOIN
    EmployeeAssignment ea
ON
    e.EmpId = ea.EmpId
INNER JOIN
    CustomerSite cs
ON
    ea.CustId = cs.CustId
GROUP BY   
e.EmpName,
cs.SiteName
HAVING ea.EndDate = 
        (
        SELECT 
            MIN(ea.EndDate)
        FROM 
             EmployeeAssignment ea
         WHERE
            GETDATE() BETWEEN ea.StartDate AND ea.EndDate);
```

Comment: doesn't work becuase you can't have the ea.EndDate in the having clause without it being in a aggregate or in the order by clause, but with it in the ordeby clasue doesn't show all the results. Thank you for the try though

Comment: you can place the ea.EndDate after the HAVING inside a MIN aggregate as we are looking for the minimum date